# What SWING elements can be added to ButtonGroup that make sense?

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup

Although, every `AbstractButton` can be added to the `ButtonGroup` (according to the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html)), i wanted to ask, which elements really make sense to get added.

The following two definitely do:

- `JRadioButton`
- `JRadioButtonMenuItem`

I wanted to know about:

- `JCheckBox` <- which, like `JRadioButton`, inherits from `JToggleButton`
- Any other `AbstractButton`

Comment: From the api doc *It wouldn't make sense to put an instance of JButton or JMenuItem in a button group because JButton and JMenuItem don't implement the selected state.*

Comment: Great comment @HarryJoy but it seems it is (at least part of) the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I know, its just a part. I also came to know this line from doc site *The Swing release supports radio buttons with the JRadioButton and ButtonGroup classes*, So I guess ButtonGroup is mainly intended to use with JRadioButton.

Comment: Adding `JCheckBox` instances to a `ButtonGroup` would be particularly confusing to the hapless user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ButtonGroup` is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of buttons. Creating a set of buttons with the same `ButtonGroup` object means that turning "on" one of those buttons turns off all other buttons in the group.

A `ButtonGroup` can be used with any set of objects that inherit from `AbstractButton`. Typically a `ButtonGroup` contains instances of `JRadioButton`, JRadioButtonMenuItem, or `JToggleButton`. It wouldn't make sense to put an instance of `JButton` or `JMenuItem` in a `ButtonGroup` because `JButton` and `JMenuItem` don't implement the selected state.

Initially, all buttons in the group are unselected. Once any button is selected, one button is always selected in the group. There is no way to turn a button programmatically to "off", in order to clear the button group. To give the appearance of "none selected", add an invisible `JRadioButton` to the group and then programmatically select that button to turn off all the displayed `JRadioButtons`. For example, a normal button with the label "none" could be wired to select the invisible `JRadioButton`.

For examples and further information on using `ButtonGroups` [see How to Use `JRadioButtons`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton), a section in The Java Tutorial.

Comment: _Once any button is selected, one button is always selected in the group_ This is not true as of Java 1.6

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks for your helpful comment, and feel free to edit any part of it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer above - there is a way, to create ButtonGroup that will allow to clear selection in group (the state when none of the group buttons will be selected) without any additional code - just extend ButtonGroup and override setSelected method like this:

```
public void setSelected ( ButtonModel model, boolean selected )
{
    if ( selected || !unselectable )
    {
        super.setSelected ( model, selected );
    }
    else
    {
        clearSelection ();
    }
}
```

That will allow buttons to become unselected.